# Difference between Canvas and Camera in Unity 2D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, difference

We put elements on canvass does.How do we see canvas even when the camera is not aligned in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Canvas have three Render modes:

1. Screen space - Overlay: Do not need camera to render UI elements.
   They always render on top of any Camera of any depth value.
2. Screen space - Camera: Need camera reference to render UI element. If no
   camera reference assigned, it takes camera with tag "MainCamera"
   automatically. If no camera found with tag "MainCamera", then if
   won't render any UI element.
3. World space: Completely camera dependent.

More info can be found here about Canvas RenderMode: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UICanvas.html